# Dynamically create HTML table from sql query result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how can i write the sql query to get rows from multiple MySQL table and then output it to an HTML table as the format below.
I've been trying this for hours and I'm still not getting it.

Below is the HTML structure that I am trying to create

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
|student_id  | full_name  |  TERM 1 | TERM2 |  TERM 3 | TERM 4 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|     1      |   John Doe |   67    |   90  |   NA    |   NA   |
|     2      |   John Smi |   NA    |   NA  |   NA    |   NA   |
|     3      |   Doe John |   88    |   66  |   NA    |   NA   |
|     4      |   Mike Doe |   57    |   78  |   NA    |   NA   |
|     5      |   Doe Mike |   NA    |   NA  |   NA    |   NA   |
|     6      |   Sam  Doe |   NA    |   NA  |   NA    |   NA   |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

And Here are the structures for the MySQL tables

```
--------------------------
| student_id | full_name |
--------------------------
|     1      | John Doe  |
|     2      | John Smi  |
|     3      | Doe John  |
|     4      | Mike Doe  |
|     5      | Doe Mike  |
|     6      | Sam  Doe  |
--------------------------

------------------------
| exam_id | exam_name  | 
------------------------
|   11    |   TERM 1   |
|   12    |   TERM 2   |
|   13    |   TERM 3   |
|   14    |   TERM 4   |
------------------------


----------------------------------------
| subject_id  | exam_id | subject_name | 
----------------------------------------
|      1      |    11   | mathematics  |
|      2      |    11   | english      |
|      3      |    11   | physics      |
|      4      |    12   | mathematics  |
|      5      |    12   | english      |
|      6      |    12   | physics      |
----------------------------------------


---------------------------------------------
| subject_id |   marks    |   student_id    |
---------------------------------------------
|      1     |   67       |        1        |
|      2     |   54       |        4        |
|      3     |   88       |        3        |
|      4     |   90       |        1        |
|      5     |   78       |        4        |
|      6     |   66       |        3        |
---------------------------------------------
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which part are you stuck at?  Do you have any code?

Comment: @danronmoon Actually all my queries have not been working, if i may get an idea on how to go about it

Comment: A student can have more than one mark in the same term right (even though there are none in your example)? What would you want in that case? The average among all the marks for that student/term?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia, yes a student can have more than one marks in a term. so i'll like to generate a table with the student's name, the exam type and the corresponding marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the query you want:

```
select s.student_id,
       s.full_name,
       avg(case when te.exam_name = 'TERM 1' then sm.marks else null end) as term_1,
       avg(case when te.exam_name = 'TERM 2' then sm.marks else null end) as term_2,
       avg(case when te.exam_name = 'TERM 3' then sm.marks else null end) as term_3,
       avg(case when te.exam_name = 'TERM 4' then sm.marks else null end) as term_4
  from students s
  left join subject_marks sm
    on s.student_id = sm.student_id
  left join subject_exams se
    on sm.subject_id = se.subject_id
  left join term_exams te
    on se.exam_id = te.exam_id
group by s.student_id,
         s.full_name
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd1c82/1/0

As for outputting it to an HTML table, you want to look at a PHP/MySQL tutorial.

Comment: @Brain Demilia, Please can you explain to me why you explain to me why you used the average function in the query?

Comment: @user1862764 Because if a student has more than 1 mark in the same term it will show the average. If they just have 1, it will show just that 1. No matter what you have to use an aggregate function to get 1 row per student and name.